# How come I see infra-red in my photos?

Tags: canon, infrared

So I noticed I can see infra-red color (which looks blue) in my Canon 77D photos, which made me wonder - how can that be? I mean, if invisible color becomes visible, that means the sensor is distorting the colors. Does that happen to all colors (and I just don't notice) or is it by design for the infra-red spectrum only? (and if so - why?)

Comment: I don't think you're seeing what you think you're seeing. But, you'll have to provide some examples for anyone to give you any insight into whatever phenomenon is occurring.

Comment: IR always looks pink on my cameras...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone can test their camera for IR, just image your TV remote. Likely you will see it's IR output as a spot of colored light. What color will this spot be?

The camera's imaging chip is a matrix of red, green, and blue filters (the three light primary colors). In other words, the light sensitive sites are covered with a transparent overlay colored using a transparent dye. These dyes are not perfect, it they were, they would need to be much darker than they are. So what is happening is, some IR radiation is leaking through to the imaging site they overlay. If its the blue filters that are leaking, then you will see blue instead of the invisible IR. Leaking filters, this is called cross talk. Seeing blue for IR is called false color imaging,